# How to filter strings having some sequence of characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Consider that I have a list of user names and I need to search for a user with a **search key**. For every username, if it matches the key I will add it to the search results, as indicated by the following **javascript** code:

```
var username_1 = "amal";
var username_2 = "sayed ali mohamed";
var search_key = "am"; 
var index = username_1.search(search_key);
if(index != -1){
     console.log('Username 1 matched')
}

index = username_2.search(search_key);
if(index != -1){
     console.log('Username 2 matched')
}
```

As obvious, only `username1` matches the query, but it's noted that both names have the letters 'a' and 'm'. So, if I wanted both names to match, I need to use the following regular expression: **.*a.*m.***

**Problem:** given a string of characters 'c<sub>1</sub>c<sub>2</sub>c<sub>3</sub>...c<sub>n</sub>', how to convert it to the following string of characters '.*c<sub>1</sub>.*c<sub>2</sub>.*c<sub>3</sub>  ...  .*c<sub>n</sub>.*' in an efficient way with javascript ?

Comment: I searched a lot , but didn't find an efficient way. All people are doing it using a for loop

Comment: do you have a list of usernames and you want to search through them ? can you have them in an array ?

Comment: Yes, I can have them in an array

Comment: @AhmedHussein `console.log("zzz".search(/a*m*/), "am".search(/a*m*/))`

Comment: This is not my actual problem. I defined my problem as follows:  
given a string of characters 'c1c2c3...cn', how to convert it to the following string of characters '*c1*c2*c3...*cn*' in an efficient way with javascript ?  

That is, I need an efficient way to make such conversion

Comment: like this: `var searchkey = "abcdef";
console.log('*' + searchkey.split('').join('*') +'*')`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: the regular expression you want is of the form `/a.*b.*c/`, not `/a*b*c*/`. The latter expression would only match strings like `aaaabbccccc`, and would not match `axxxbxxxc`.

Second: the easiest way to convert from `"abc"` to `/a.*b.*c/` is to split the string on an empty delimiter, then join the resulting array with the wildcard:

```
var input = "abc";
var regex = new RegExp(input.split("").join(".*"));
```

Comment: To the user who suggested an edit: This regular expression is unanchored (no `^` or `$`), so a leading or trailing `.*` is unnecessary.